# Error calling Reports API v1

Tags: python, google-api, google-api-python-client, google-admin-sdk

I'm getting an error while calling the Reports API:

```
<HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/admin/reports/v1/usage/users/all/dates/2013-08-01?alt=json&maxResults=1 returned "Caller does not have access to the customers reporting data.">
```

Have anyone seen this error before? What am I missing?
I just can't see why this is showing or what I should be checking.

Regards.

EDIT:

Auth:

```
        credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(
            service_account_name='5163XXXXX@developer.gserviceaccount.com',
            private_key=oauth2_private_key,
            scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.reports.usage.readonly')

        # https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/thread_safety
        http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())

        service = apiclient.discovery.build('admin', 'reports_v1', http=http)
```

The actual call:

```
result = service.userUsageReport().get(
    userKey='all',
    date='2013-08-01',
    maxResults=1).execute()
```

Other APIs just work fine with that service account.
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.reports.usage.readonly' has been properly added to OAuth2 domain config page.

Comment: who are you authenticating as? Reseller or super admin within the Google Apps instance? It helps to see your actual code rather than just the error you are getting.

Comment: Hi Jay. I'm editing the question to show some code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
    credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(
        service_account_name='5163XXXXX@developer.gserviceaccount.com',
        private_key=oauth2_private_key,
        scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.reports.usage.readonly',
        sub='super-admin@yourdomain.com')
```

when using Service Accounts with Admin SDK, you still need to act on behalf of an admin within the Google Apps instance.

Also, make sure that the Service Account Client ID has been granted rights to use the Reports API scopes in the Google Apps Control Panel. The Google Drive docs [describe this process well](https://developers.google.com/drive/delegation#delegate_domain-wide_authority_to_your_service_account), just sub in the Reports scopes instead.

Comment: Still no luck. This time I get an AccessTokenRefreshError (could not connect: access_denied). For other Admin SDK calls I use prn='super-admin@yourdomain.com', but it gives the same error in this Reports calls.

Comment: see updated answer. You need to make sure the Service account has been granted access to the given scopes in the CPanel.

Comment: Solved. I thought I had added the usage scope as well as the audit one (admin.reports.audit.readonly), but I was wrong.
Thank you!

Comment: Seems to assume Oauth 1.0. The [Google Dive example cited above](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/delegation#delegate_domain-wide_authority_to_your_service_account) by @JayLee  directs you to "Select Manage third party OAuth Client access", which leads to docs about 1.0 being deprecated.   Suggestions for 2.0?

Comment: OK. Working. In [Using OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount) under **Delegating domain-wide authority to the service account**, should change`s/Manage third party OAuth Client access/Manage API client access/`. @JayLee